# javascript create url from form elements handling checkboxes

Tags: javascript

So I had been using this generic code to create a URL from the form elements

```
function submiturl() {
    url="Search.do?call=JS"; 
    var elem = document.getElementById('searchInput').elements;
    for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        url = url + "&" + escape(elem[i].name) + "=" + escape(elem[i].value);
    }
    url = url.substring(0,(url.length-1));
   alert(url);
}
```

however it does not handle checkboxes properly - I only want to add to the URL if the checkboxes are checked.  So if you had this html

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="searchInput" id ="searchInput">
    <input name="first" type="checkbox" value="123"/>One two three
    <input name="second" type="checkbox" value="456"/>Four five six
    <button type="button" onClick="submiturl();">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

it will create the URL using the value for both checkboxes regardless if they were checked or not.

So how can I modify my javascript to check if it is a checkbox and is checked?

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using if (elem[i].checked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function submiturl() {
    var url="Search.do?call=JS", 
        els = document.getElementById("searchInput").elements
    ;
    for(var el, i = 0, n = els.length; i < n; i++) {
        el = els[i];
        if (el.checked || el.type !== "checkbox") {
            url += "&" + encodeURIComponent(el.name) + 
                   "=" + encodeURIComponent(el.value)
            ;
        }
    }
    alert(url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your for-loop do this:

```
if (elem[i].type != "checkbox" || elem[i].checked)
    url = url + ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a checkbox?

```
typeof elem[i].attributes['type'] != 'undefined' &&
elem[i].attributes['type'].value == 'checkbox'
```

Is it checked?

```
typeof elem[i].attributes['checked'] != 'undefined' &&
elem[i].attributes['checked'].value == 'checked'
```